# Qt 5.2 RC1 "Exec format error": android deployment on virtual Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: android, qt, ubuntu, virtualbox, qt5

I’m trying now for three weeks to get a simple Hello World app working on a AVD (arm). Under Windows (64 bit) there are no issues but I want to create a virtual workspace via VirtualBox using Ubuntu 13.04 LTS (32 bit) and Qt 5.2 RC1. Please don’t tell me to use Qt natively, I know that it is slower and so on, this workspace should work on multiple computers without doing a new Qt setup every single time.

I added the SDK, NDK, Ant and OpenJDK, as described in [this documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/android-support.html). I tried with a Qt Designer GUI including a Button and a Checkbox, and furthermore with [this example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.8/creator-android-app-tutorial.html).

The result is always the same:

> ```
> :-1: Fehler: error trying to exec '/opt/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as': execv: Exec format error
> :-1: Fehler: [main.o] Error 1
> ```

The full compiling report:

> ```
> 14:55:19: Führe Schritte für Projekt accelbubble aus...
> 14:55:19: Starte "/usr/bin/make" clean
> rm -f qrc_accelbubble.cpp
> rm -f main.o qrc_accelbubble.o
> rm -f *~ core *.core
> 14:55:19: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/make" wurde normal beendet.
> 14:55:19: Unveränderte Konfiguration, qmake-Schritt wird übersprungen.
> 14:55:19: Starte "/usr/bin/make"
> /opt/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-g++ -c -Wno-psabi -march=armv5te -mtune=xscale -msoft-float -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector -fno-short-enums -DANDROID -Wa,--noexecstack -std=gnu++0x -g -g -gdwarf-2 -marm -O0 -fno-omit-frame-pointer -Wall -Wno-psabi -W -D_REENTRANT -fPIE -DQT_OS_ANDROID_GCC_48_WORKAROUND -DQT_QML_DEBUG -DQT_DECLARATIVE_DEBUG -DQT_QUICK_LIB -DQT_SVG_LIB -DQT_QML_LIB -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_SENSORS_LIB -DQT_NETWORK_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/mkspecs/android-g++ -I../accelbubble -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtQuick -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtSvg -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtQml -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtWidgets -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtXml -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtSensors -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtNetwork -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtGui -I/opt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0-rc1/android_armv5/include/QtCore -I. -I/opt/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/include -I/opt/android-ndk-r9b/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.8/libs/armeabi/include -I/opt/android-ndk-r9b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include -I. -o main.o ../accelbubble/main.cpp
> arm-linux-androideabi-g++: error trying to exec '/opt/android-ndk-r9b/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.8/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/as': execv: Exec format error
> make: *** [main.o] Error 1
> 14:55:25: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/make" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
> Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts accelbubble(Kit: Android für armeabi (GCC 4.8, Qt 5.2.0))
> Bei der Ausführung von Schritt 'Make'
> 14:55:25: Verstrichene Zeit: 00:06.
> ```

I am running Qt Creator as root. I searched various forums for this issue but couldn’t find any solution, with everything I do I end up with this error again, maybe you can help me. If you need more information please let me know.

Regards,
Clemens

Comment: To indicate that your problem is solved, you need to post an answer below, and then mark it as "accepted" with the green checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. My problem was in the ndk folder. I extracted the downloaded `tar.bz2` file in a wrong way which resulted in broken links. Try to download the file again, check the md5 sum, extract the file using a gui archive manager and finally adjust the ndk folder in qtcreator->tools->options->Android . Hope this helps